# Why does redmine not use the development and test environments?

Tags: redmine

Why does redmine not use the development and test environments?

In the [official installation guide](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall) they only show one environment when setting up the databases, advise to run `bundler` skipping dev and test, and run the rails server in production mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this instruction describes the installation process only for server (which runs in Production mode). I think it is done this way not to confuse new users (who do not have a lot of knowledge in Rails)

You can easily use this instruction to setup Redmine locally (I did it successfully several times ;). In order to install Redmine locally you should change only few points in the instruction.